# WSDL XSD elements sequence

Tags: web-services, soap, xsd, wsdl

Does the sequence order of XSD elements have a significant impact on client aplications?

Imagine that a clinet application that is givven a different order. Should that influence it in any way?

Additionally is there a special case where the order read by the client application is different that the XSD?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

1) It depends on how the "contract" is written... which of the XSD "compositors" is used (sequence, choice and all):

- Sequence: the elements must show in that exact order and repetition as identified by cardinality constraints. Repeat as needed...
- Choice: for any occurrence of the choice, exactly one from the options particles may appear. If the choice is repeatable, then it means those options may repeat, but in no particular order.
- All: elements may appear in any order; in XSD 1.0 version, each element may occur at most once; XSD 1.1 relaxed this constraint, which means more of the same may occur.

If you're providing a client application with elements using an order different than that prescribed using the associated `xsd:sequence` then an XSD validator must flag the XML as invalid. It should not mater for an xsd:all or a repeating choice.

2) If you're processing the XML using an XML API, then `the order read by the client application` is always that in the XML instance (not the XSD). If you're processing the XML using some sort of XSD to code binding technology, such as JAXB or XML serialization in .NET, then as long as the XML is valid, the concept of "ordering" is affected... corresponding references within a list will still reflect that encountered in the XML file; however, in object orientation there is no ordering of fields in a class definition (proprietary annotations/tags may still capture this as metadata for the purposes of serializing it back correctly, but that is just a binding technology "ism" rather than a OO concept).

Then there are the really bad XSD contracts, where semantics of elements are implied by the relative position of the element in the parent's node collection (e.g. first customer is "principal", second would be "co-applicant", etc.) which makes this discussion even fuzzier...